# How do I install boto3 on EMR zeppelin

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, boto3, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am writing some pyspark code using zeppelin notebook on AWS EMR.
When I tried to import boto3, here is the error

```
Fail to execute line 1: import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1491115636333819951.py", line 380, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

how I can install boto3 in this environment? or is there anyway I can use AWS+Zeppelin+boto3?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out . need to install in the master node (from ssh connection)